# Corrected view of user folders

Tags: powershell

I have a server that stores user folders. For some time, I saw that some folders do not have a username but have a Documents folder.

When I right click and select properties, there is the name of user.

How can I give the good name on the folders? I have tried with a script

```
For Example, I have a different folders :
AZE
RTY
UIO
OPQ
Documents - in properties desktop.ini the owner is DFG
Documents - in properties desktop.ini the owner is GHJ
Documents - in properties desktop.ini the owner is KLM
WXC
VBN
```

Thanks you in advance for your answers !

Comment: [Is this the issue you are having?](https://serverfault.com/questions/566279/shared-home-folders-on-file-server-listed-as-my-documents)

Comment: Yes, for the administrator be able to read the "Users" int their usual form, 'AZE' for example, not "Documents"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this at work previously by using a File Screen to block desktop.ini on the file share.  This was on a Windows 2008 R2 & Windows 2012 R2 File Server.  The File Screen configuration is done using File Server Resource Manager.

This TechNet link has some instructions:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754163%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your link. I try to realize this instructions.

Comment: I have folders that are already called "Document", does the setting work anyway?

Comment: I was thinking used a script to modify the folders and then used the settings on the server

Comment: In the example you gave, technically the folder name is not "Documents", it's just being displayed that way because desktop.ini exists.  If you remove desktop.ini from each of those folders, it will be displayed correctly.  That's why I've used a File Screen in the past, to block the auto-creation of desktop.ini.